# HTML5 <input> doesn't respond to touch event properly

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I am developing a mobile webpage which has an input box:

```
<input id="searcher" data-role="none" type="search" placeholder="Search Friends"
                   style="position:absolute; background-color:white; display:block; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
                   -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; margin: 0px;">
```

The problem is the input box doesn't get focus after the user tap the input box (The cursor and the keyboard do not appear, it is the same both on Android Chrome and IOS safari). The input box will get focus only if you press the input box for a while (like 1 second).

I am not sure this is the default behaviour of input box. How could I get solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: First I'd recommend removing inline CSS so that its easier to maintain *all* your `<input />` boxes.

Comment: Are you by any chance using any libraries that handles touch events? HammerJS, fastclick, etc?

Comment: "-moz-border-radius" has not only been unneeded for quite some time, it's been ignored for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly double check what you are using and loading on the top of
   your document. If you are using something like jQuery Mobile or
   another mobile framework they could be translating your code
   differently in accordance to their solutions.
2. Secondly; remove the inline (CSS) code and simply make a class,
   especially since your are declaring `moz and webkit` -- also assure
   your document is HTML5 doctype and the mark-up is clean missing no
   close tags etc `</div>` *EG*. http://validator.w3.org/
3. Thirdly; test on multiple devices to assure your accuracy in your
   Q+A as you may have some settings enabled on your specific device
   your testing on; making it harder to see actual result. I would
   suggest testing on a few mobile devices, or assure the only device
   your testing on doesn't have additional mobile browsing settings
   enabled.